# float:left Not Working - Text Disappears

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website. My float element is not working as it should. But that's not the only thing, when I add the float: left element the navbar disappear. I need my navbar to be floated to the left.

HTML Code:

```css
    body {
      font-family: 'Open-sans', sans-serif, Helvetica;
      text-align: center;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    #main_navbar {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      float: right;
      position: absolute;
      top: 35px;
      right: 20px;
    }
    
    #main_navbar li {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline-block;
      min-width: 5em;
    }
    
    #main_navbar li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: hidden;
       color: #68cedd;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .dropdown:active {
      color: #32673f;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      min-width: 200px;
      right: 50%;
      transform: translate(50%,0);
      position: absolute;
      padding: 10px 0;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      display: block;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
    }
    
    #image_symbol {
      width: 10em;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    header {
      height: 95px;
      width: 100%;
      padding-right: 30px;
      margin-left: -20px;
      margin-top: -20px;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
    
    #main_navbar li a.active, ul#main_navbar li a:hover {
      color: #32673f;
    }
    
    #navbar {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta  charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>My Cycle - Home</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
     </head>
     <body>
      <header>
       <div id="heading">
        <img src="http://i.imgsafe.org/79ba3b5.png" id="image_symbol"></img>
        <h2 style="position: relative; top: -100px; left: 120px">MY CYCLE</h2>
       </div>
       <div id="navbar">
        <ul id="main_navbar">
            <li>
             <a href="#" style="z-index: -1" class="active">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
               <a class="dropbtn" style="z-index: -1">Rent</a>
               <div class="dropdown-content">
                 <a href="rental/mountain_bikes.html">Mountain Bikes</a>
                 <a href="rental/hybrid_bikes.html">Hybrid Bikes</a>
                 <a href="rental/road_bikes.html">Road Bikes</a>
                 <a href="rental/city_bikes.html">City Bikes</a>
               </div>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="faq.html" style="z-index: -1">FAQ's</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="about.html" style="z-index: -1">About</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
      </header>
      <section>
       
      </section>
      <footer>
       
      </footer>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "Not working as it should"? You need to explain your problem

Comment: When i use float left the text disappears .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the position absolute, it works:

```css
body {
      font-family: 'Open-sans', sans-serif, Helvetica;
      text-align: center;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    #main_navbar {
      
      /* REMOVE THIS ELEMENT */
      /*position: absolute;*/
      
      
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      float: right;
      top: 35px;
      right: 20px;
    }
    
    #main_navbar li {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline-block;
      min-width: 5em;
    }
    
    #main_navbar li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: hidden;
       color: #68cedd;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .dropdown:active {
      color: #32673f;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      min-width: 200px;
      right: 50%;
      transform: translate(50%,0);
      position: absolute;
      padding: 10px 0;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      display: block;
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
    }
    
    #image_symbol {
      width: 10em;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    header {
      height: 95px;
      width: 100%;
      padding-right: 30px;
      margin-left: -20px;
      margin-top: -20px;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
    
    #main_navbar li a.active, ul#main_navbar li a:hover {
      color: #32673f;
    }
    
    #navbar {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta  charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>My Cycle - Home</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
     </head>
     <body>
      <header>
       <div id="heading">
        <img src="http://i.imgsafe.org/79ba3b5.png" id="image_symbol"></img>
        <h2 style="position: relative; top: -100px; left: 120px">MY CYCLE</h2>
       </div>
       <div id="navbar">
        <ul id="main_navbar">
            <li>
             <a href="#" style="z-index: -1" class="active">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
               <a class="dropbtn" style="z-index: -1">Rent</a>
               <div class="dropdown-content">
                 <a href="rental/mountain_bikes.html">Mountain Bikes</a>
                 <a href="rental/hybrid_bikes.html">Hybrid Bikes</a>
                 <a href="rental/road_bikes.html">Road Bikes</a>
                 <a href="rental/city_bikes.html">City Bikes</a>
               </div>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="faq.html" style="z-index: -1">FAQ's</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="about.html" style="z-index: -1">About</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
      </header>
      <section>
       
      </section>
      <footer>
       
      </footer>
     </body>
    </html>
```